# How to convert nested object into an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, lodash

I have an array with multiple objects. In this array each objects having two or more sub objects. I want to get together all sub objects into an array of data. How to do with javascript?

```
var array1 = [
  {
    "dfgasg24":{
      name:"a",
      id:1
    },
    "dfgare24":{
      name:"b",
      id:2
    }
  },
  {
    "wegasg24":{
      name:"ab",
      id:76
    },
    "yugasg24":{
      name:"bc",
      id:34
    },
    "yugasg26":{
      name:"dc",
      id:45
    }
  }
]
```

The output which i want to be like this,

```
var result = [
    {
        name:"a",
        id:1
    },
    {
        name:"b",
        id:2
    },
    {
        name:"ab",
        id:76
    },
    {
        name:"bc",
        id:34
    },
    {
        name:"dc",
        id:45
    }
];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a combined approach with iterating over the array and over the keys for building a flat array.

```js
var array = [{ "dfgasg24": { name: "a", id: 1 }, "dfgare24": { name: "b", id: 2 } }, { "wegasg24": { name: "ab", id: 76 }, "yugasg24": { name: "bc", id: 34 }, "yugasg26": { name: "dc", id: 45 } }],
    result = array.reduce(function (r, o) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            r.push(o[k]);
        });
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `Array.flatMap()` with `Object.values()`:

```js
const array = [{ "dfgasg24": { name: "a", id: 1 }, "dfgare24": { name: "b", id: 2 } }, { "wegasg24": { name: "ab", id: 76 }, "yugasg24": { name: "bc", id: 34 }, "yugasg26": { name: "dc", id: 45 } }];

const result = array.flatMap(Object.values);

console.log(result);
```

If `Array.flatMap()` is not supported, use `Array.map()` with `Object.values()`, and flatten the results by spreading into `Array.concat()`:

```js
const array = [{ "dfgasg24": { name: "a", id: 1 }, "dfgare24": { name: "b", id: 2 } }, { "wegasg24": { name: "ab", id: 76 }, "yugasg24": { name: "bc", id: 34 }, "yugasg26": { name: "dc", id: 45 } }];

const result = [].concat(...array.map(Object.values));

console.log(result);
```

If all objects' keys are unique, you also use Object.assign() to combine all objects to a single one, then extract the values to an array with `Object.values()`:

```js
const array = [{ "dfgasg24": { name: "a", id: 1 }, "dfgare24": { name: "b", id: 2 } }, { "wegasg24": { name: "ab", id: 76 }, "yugasg24": { name: "bc", id: 34 }, "yugasg26": { name: "dc", id: 45 } }];

const result = Object.values(Object.assign({}, ...array));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 3):

use `_.values` to get object values

```
var res = _.flatMap(array1, _.values)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
answer=[];
for(elem of array){
var arr=[];
 for(obj of elem){
   arr.push(obj);
 }
answer.push(arr);
}
alert(answer);
```

Loop trough the main array, and replace each elem with an array.