# how to convert nested object into array of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, object

Hi i have a situation where i want to convert `array of object` into `array of array`

here is my **targeted** `array` of `objects` which looks like this

```
(32) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]0: Object1: Object2: Object3: Object4: Object5: Object6: Object7: Object8: Object9: Object10: Object11: Object12: Object13: Object14: Object15: Object16: Object17: Object18: Object19: Object20: Object21: Object22: Object23: Object24: Object25: Object26: Object27: Object28: Object29: Object30: Object31: Objectlength: 32__proto__: Array(0)
```

**i think it has the structure like this :**

```
targetObject = [

{location: "MUGABALA  KOLAR ROAD", latitude: 13.108435679884, longitude: 77.890262391016},

{location: "pune", latitude: 18.6202008, longitude: 73.7908073},

{location: "RAJARAJESHWARI NAGAR BANGLORE", latitude: 12.901112992767, longitude: 77.5037757}

];
```

**My desired Output:**

```
    $resultant = [
             ["MUGABALA  KOLAR ROAD", 13.108435679884, 77.890262391016],

              ["pune",  18.6202008, 73.7908073],

            ["RAJARAJESHWARI NAGAR BANGLORE", 12.901112992767, 77.5037757]

];
```

Comment: `targetObject.map(x=> Object.keys(x).map(k=> x[k]) )`

Comment: Refer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427699/how-to-convert-nested-object-into-an-array-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the result of [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values).

For older user agents, you could use a [polyfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries).

```js
var array = [{ location: "MUGABALA  KOLAR ROAD", latitude: 13.108435679884, longitude: 77.890262391016 }, { location: "pune", latitude: 18.6202008, longitude: 73.7908073 }, { location: "RAJARAJESHWARI NAGAR BANGLORE", latitude: 12.901112992767, longitude: 77.5037757 }],
    result = array.map(Object.values);
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Note: `Object.values` is a experimental technology

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [**Object.values()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) and **[Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example)**:

```
var results = targetObject.map(function(obj){
      return Object.values(obj);
});
console.log(results);
```

**Demo:**

```js
targetObject = [

{location: "MUGABALA  KOLAR ROAD", latitude: 13.108435679884, longitude: 77.890262391016},

{location: "pune", latitude: 18.6202008, longitude: 73.7908073},

{location: "RAJARAJESHWARI NAGAR BANGLORE", latitude: 12.901112992767, longitude: 77.5037757}

];

var results = targetObject.map(function(obj){
      return Object.values(obj);
});
console.log(results);
```

**Object.values()**:

> The Object.values() method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable property values, in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).