# How can we convert an nested object in an array into an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

I have the object as below:

```
const givenData = {
        "ProcessA": { "state": "on", "used": "16.41" },
        "ProcessB": { "state": "off", "used": "16.40" },
        "ProcessC": { "state": "off", "used": "16.36" },
        "ProcessD": { "state": "on", "used": "16.45" }
  };
```

And I want my output as below two different objects:

```
  let ob1= {
     "ProcessA":"on",
     "ProcessB":"off",
     "ProcessC":"off",
     "ProcessD":"on",
   }

  let obj2={
     "ProcessA":"16.41",
     "ProcessB":"16.40",
     "ProcessC":"16.36",
     "ProcessD":"16.45",
   }
```

can anyone suggest me if there is any easy solution for this?

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? A simple `for...in...` would be enough (if you know the names of the properties)

Comment: Read up on `Object.entries()` and `Array.map()`

Comment: I think this your answer. please checked it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44520500/how-to-convert-nested-object-into-array-of-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a reusable function to achieve this:

```js
function getObj(obj, givenKey) {
  return Object
           .keys(obj)
           .reduce((final, key) => ({ ...final, [key]: obj[key][givenKey] }), {})
}

const obj1 = getObj(givenData, "state")
const obj2 = getObj(givenData, "used")
```

Comment: @Raghu Doing it separately for properties ``state`` and ``used`` makes the process inefficient. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you want:

```js
const givenData = {
    "ProcessA": { "state": "on", "used": "16.41" },
    "ProcessB": { "state": "off", "used": "16.40" },
    "ProcessC": { "state": "off", "used": "16.36" },
    "ProcessD": { "state": "on", "used": "16.45" }
};

const a = {};
const b = {};
for (k in givenData) {
    a[k] = givenData[k].state;
    b[k] = givenData[k].used;
}
console.log(a, b)
```

Comment: Don’t always add “here’s what you want” or nothing to your answers. Instead describe the problem with OPs attempt and the changes you made to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```js
const givenData = {
    "ProcessA": { "state": "on", "used": "16.41" },
    "ProcessB": { "state": "off", "used": "16.40" },
    "ProcessC": { "state": "off", "used": "16.36" },
    "ProcessD": { "state": "on", "used": "16.45" }
};

const {obj1, obj2} = Object.keys(givenData).reduce((acc, cur) => ({obj1:{...acc.obj1, [cur]: givenData[cur].state}, obj2:{...acc.obj2,[cur]:givenData[cur].used}}), {});

console.log(obj1)
console.log(obj2)
```